# Overriding code behind layout changes by loading XAML file

Tags: wpf, xml, xaml

I have a WPF app in which my client wants to be able to write a custom xml file to change the default layout set by an existing XAML file. What I am trying to do is fall back to the XAML layout if there are errors in the xml file I am parsing. I have the code behind done for parsing the xml file and changing the default layout but I'm trying to find a way to load the XAML file if something goes wrong. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need an ability to load a layout dynamically, here is one possible solution. This can be achieved by using the [XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) class. The process is quite straightforward, just use the [XamlReader.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590398.aspx) method to load a serialized content from a stream (xml or whatever).

However, i can't see why you don't want to just validate the user-defined xml file, and if something is wrong, don't do anything.

Comment: Yeah, your suggestion about validating the xml file is what I was leaning towards but it made me curious about other ways to do it. Thanks for the reply.